# appending txtfile to combobox tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

I want to put text from a txtfile in a combobox in tkinter with a def function and return it.
I never did that before.
And I don't know how to do it.

I can't find how to do it the right way on this Stackoverflowwebsite and on the internet.

The text in the file is like :

```
A
B
C
D
```

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: What part of the problem do you need help with? Do you know how to read a file? Do you know how to create a tkinter app? Do you know how to create a combobox? Those are pretty fundamental things, but if you know them you know everything you need to answer your own question.

Comment: I know how to create  aT kinter app and  how to create an empty combobox with a label in front of it.I just don't know how to fill it with text from a textfile.

Comment: Load the text file into a list, then use `values` option of `Combobox`.